# Restore postgresql 9.4 database from files

Tags: database, postgresql, restore

I have a tar.gz which is supposed to contain a complete Postgres 9.4 database backup.

I attemped to restore the database using pg_restore, but I realised (after I unpacked the file) that it has the same structure as the `/var/lib/postgresql/9.4/main` directory running on my localhost.

So I stopped the postgresql service running on localhost, I replaced my main directory with the one from the archive as described here:  [Restore postgresql from files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17865969/restore-postgresql-from-files).

Moreover I've set owner and permissions in a recursive manner like this:

```
chown -R postgres:postgres /var/lib/postgresql/9.4/main/
chmod -R 700  /var/lib/postgresql/9.4/main/.
```

I've restarted the service:

```
root@EED-015-LIN:~# service postgresql status
9.3/main (port 5433): online
9.4/main (port 3007): online,recovery
...But when I try to connect using psql
postgres@EED-015-LIN:~$ psql -p 3007
psql: FATAL:  the database system is starting up
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Maybe it's still recovering? Restoring from the database files is really a last-ditch effort. Having a clean `pg_dump` produced file is way better.

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're missing. If you backed up a hot standby and want to make it r/w on your machine, make sure to remove the recovery.conf file.

Comment: @tadman define better! pg_dump is safer, for sure. But backing up the whole cluster is a whole lot faster. I have recently set up a replication cluster on my machine that is a hot standby for my production database. If I want an up-to-date version of my production database for development purposes, I simple stop the replication on my machine and copy the whole cluster into a new one. This takes like 3 minutes; pg_dump takes hours to do the same.

Comment: If you can shut down your database and get a consistent snapshot, sure, the files approach is fine. Not every database can be brought down, though, so `pg_dump` is the best plan in that case. If you can take LVM snapshots, or use [drbd](http://drbd.linbit.com/) you have other options as well. Just keep in mind that copying the files of an operating database may not lead to a successful restore. Don't forget that [Postgres streaming replication](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Streaming_Replication) is actually not that hard to get set-up and works great.

Comment: It's also worth noting that keeping multiple copies of your production database floating around could lead to a severe security breach if you're not extremely careful. The last thing you want is un-redacted personal information sitting on your laptop in, say, the event it gets stolen or otherwise compromised.

Comment: Andre, your solution worked for me. Now I have other problems:psql: FATAL:  database locale is incompatible with operating system
DETAIL:  The database was initialized with LC_COLLATE "zh_CN.UTF-8",  which is not recognized by setlocale().
HINT:  Recreate the database with another locale or install the missing locale.

Comment: I can only connect to the instance running the database only thorugh psql. I cannot use pg_dump. And the archive that I was speaking about, was downloaded fromOSS Alyiun Interface. (Alyiun OSS is similar to Amazon Web Services RDS)

Comment: @tadman having multiple copies of my production database could lead to a security breach, indeed. It could also save my company in case someone breaks into my office and steals my servers, or if there is a fire in my IT room. I'd rather cope with the potential security breach and have an extra backup of my database... anyway, we're getting off track here ;)

Comment: @NicoleB out of curiosity, why can't you connect using pg_dump? As for the problem with LC_COLLATE, this answer may be able to help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8394789/postgresql-9-1-installation-and-database-encoding; it looks like you might need to install the zh_CN locale in you OS. Try that out.